# Removing the first character of a string if it equals something

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am practicing VBA for Access 2010.

I read all the suggested post regarding my post but did not find anything specific.
I know how to move specific characters in a string, what I do not know is how I can remove specific character that equals to something.

I want to move the character 1 or 1- from telephone numbers if one is there.

Example: 17188888888 to 7188888888 or 1-7188888888 to 7188888888

I am trying to use an if statement starting first with just removing the 1.

The phone number is entered as a string not numbers.

This is what I have started: I am getting an error message that *RemoveFirstChar* is ambiguous.

```
Public Function RemoveFirstChar(RemFstChar As String) As String
If Left(RemFstChar, 1) = "1" Then
  RemFstChar = Replace(RemFstChar, "1", "")
End If
RemoveFirstChar = RemFstChar
End Function
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have tested your function in Access 2010 and it worked just fune.. You can also use this code:

```
Public Function RemoveFirstChar(RemFstChar As String) As String
Dim TempString As String
TempString = RemFstChar
If Left(RemFstChar, 1) = "1" Then
    If Len(RemFstChar) > 1 Then
        TempString = Right(RemFstChar, Len(RemFstChar) - 1)
    End If
End If
RemoveFirstChar = TempString
End Function
```

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working but yours is working, so how would I modify this to also remove 1- from the beginning if it it there? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input - it really makes a difference! Thanks again!

Comment: After testing for the "1", you can add a second test for "-" after the first "end if" there that does the same...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing particularly wrong with your code, the "ambiguous" error message in this context is very likely to be because you have another sub or function in a different module with the same name. Search to find the duplicate name.

If you put the function in the module belonging to a form or report, it is probably best to skip "Public". If you intend the function to be used by several forms, create a new module that is not attached to a form and put the functions that are intended for all forms and reports in that.

It is nearly always good to provide the full error message and error number.