# Save/load user preference configuration file

Tags: vba, excel, synchronization, save

I would like to add SAVE/OPEN functionality to a little Excel program I wrote. To use the program, users have to fill in data and adjust settings across several sheets. I would like to save this into a configuration file to be able able to load it later.

*How should I build this SAVE/OPEN functionality?*

My idea was to group the entered data and configuration on a single sheet (let's name it `Entries`) through simple "links" (`=Sheet1!A1` for example). This sheet would be exported.

I am saving the entries into a new .xls workbook this way:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Entries").Columns("A:B").copy
Workbooks.Add
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False 'Paste only values
```

*But the challenge comes when loading the data...*

There are several examples on the net (see [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/629768-macro-to-grab-external-data-and-paste-values-into-a-master-spreadsheet.html) and [there](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/839708-importing-a-csv-file.html)) that show how to do, but always with the same problem. That is: if I just copy the data from the saved workbook (values only) to the `Entries` sheet, all my "links" will be erased. Is there a way to *synchronize* the data?

Or is the only solution to manually enter all the cell values in VBA and doing hundreds of range copies, from the exported workbook directly to the cells used by the user?

Comment: If you want to copy the formula, Excel allows for this: `ActiveSheet.YourRange.Formula = SourceWorkbook.SourceSheet.SourceRange.Formula`

Comment: When I export the entry sheets (where all user entries are grouped) to a new file, I want to save only the values because this would be an independent file.
But when I open the file I have exported, my purpose is to replace the values in the entry fields spread across various sheets.
One solution to replace the values is to enter all the destination ranges into VBA. Another solution, that I would prefer if realisable, would be to somehow synchronise the data between the exported file and the entry sheet.

Comment: I suppose I'm not fully understanding your question then, so sorry if I'm leading you in the wrong direction. Do you mean to have a workbook whose formulas point to your `Entry` workbook? In this way the values can be updated when the file is opened at the user's option, but you can also force calculation to be manual, which means a user can sync using `<F9>` if they choose.

Comment: Hi Gaffi and thanks for replying. I meant: once I have exported user settings (values only) in a new workbook, and once the program is restarted and empty from user entries, how do I copy exported settings back to the program? If I just copy everything to the Entries sheet, the links will be lost. (I also updated my question, trying to clarify it a bit. See if it helps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the **solution** found. Thanks a lot for the help!

Saving the entries...

```
Set CurSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Entries")
    maxEntries = 150
    CurSheet.copy 'a new workbook is created

    Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
    wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B" & maxEntries).Value = CurSheet.Range("A1:B" & maxEntries).Value
    wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & maxEntries).Value = CurSheet.Range("B1:B" & maxEntries).Formula

    For i = 1 To maxEntries

        'Removes the leading "=" from the formula
        tempCell = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Formula
        If Len(tempCell) > 1 Then
            wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value = Right(tempCell, Len(tempCell) - 1)
        End If

        'For empty cells
        If wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = 0 Then
            wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = ""
        End If

    Next i
```

... and loading them.

```
fullFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls),*.xls", _
        1, "Projekt öffnen", , False)

    Workbooks.Open fullFileName
    Set wbSaved = ActiveWorkbook      

    'Data copy
    maxEntries = 150

    For i = 4 To maxEntries

        If Not wbSaved.Sheets(1).Range("C" & i) = "" Then 'Skip the empty lines

            'Parsing
            c = wbSaved.Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value
            l = Len(c)
            p = InStr(1, c, "!", vbTextCompare) 'position of the !, that separates the sheet name from the cell number
            cDestSheet = Mid(c, 1, p - 1)
            cDestCell = Mid(c, p + 1, -(p - l))

            'Copy
            wbMain.Sheets(cDestSheet).Range(cDestCell).Value = wbSaved.Sheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i

    wbSaved.Close False
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea that may not be a complete answer yet, but if this sounds good, I'll elaborate some... Using your example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Entries").Columns("A:B").copy
Workbooks.Add
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False 'Paste only values
```

I would change to this (incomplete and untested code, but you should get the idea):

```
Dim CurSheet As WorkSheet

Set CurSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Entries")

With Workbooks.Add
    Sheets(1).Range("A:B").value = CurSheet.Range("A:B").value
    Sheets(2).Range("A:B").value = "'" & CurSheet.Range("A:B").formula
End With
```

What I'm doing here is taking the values as you already have and plugging them into the first sheet of the new workbook (see first line within `With` block), then also taking the text value of the formula and putting it into the second sheet, same position (see second line). In this way you can keep the values and also see where they came from. However, this is not really synchronizing like you ask for, since you would still have to manipulate the data in sheet 2 of the new book to do anything meaningful with those links.

Does this help/get you started in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Gaffi and thanks for answering. It could help. Say that I also save formula, and therefore the location. Could I write something like `MainWorkbook.Range(SavedLocationInFormula)=ExportedWorkbook.Range(...)`? Maybe should I then save the formula without the `'` or, even better, without the `=`. How could I trim the formula?

Comment: To remove the equal sign, I tried applying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633223/vba-removing-the-first-character-of-a-string-if-it-equals-something). I am copying all the formulas on the "C" column and try to do the following: `For i = 1 To max /
        tempCell = Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value 'this does not work /
        Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & i).Value = Right(tempCell, Len(tempCell) - 1)` But I am stuck when it comes to convert a range to a string. (with tempCell) Any idea?

Comment: I can't test at the moment, so I may have to get back to you, but have you tried `Right(tempCell, Len(tempCell) - 2` (swap 2 for 1)? Also, if the assignment of `tempCell` is not working, can you `MsgBox` or `Debug.Print` it after the step that you say does not work? I'd like to see what is being assigned versus what's in the cell.

Comment: In the column C are the copied formulas. I face the following problems: 1. `Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & max).Value = "'" & CurSheet.Range("B1:B" & max).Formula` does not work because of the `"'"`. Error: wrong data type. `Range.Formula` does not output a string. Therefore, `Msgbox (Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value)` does not work. // 2. The above formula without the `"'"` gives me only `#REF` errors, because the name of the source sheet is mentioned in the formula. No too bad, because the formula is still readable, but not nice, because of the several pop-ups asking the location of all the sheets.

Comment: It works now. When `Sheets.Range.Value` returns a variable or an object (I guess), `Sheets.Range.Formula` is returns a string. I then did `tempCell = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Formula / ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value = Right(tempCell, Len(tempCell) - 1)`. Great!

Comment: Good to see you solved that! Do you have any further open issues?

Comment: Hi Gaffi and sorry for the loong delay. I have had no further issues and I posted today the solution you helped me to find. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Hi @Nicolas. Glad to see you were able to do this. Normally, when a solution is helpful, the one asking the question should upvote and/or accept the answer provided ([see the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)). Since you have also provided your own solution, you should post that detail as your own answer, then accept it (after the required amount of time). Both of these actions help ensure that others may more easily find that answer in the future!

Comment: Hi @Gaffi. Thanks again for your input. I did as you advised, it is indeed much clearer that way.